# Copy all members from a struct to another struct

Tags: c++, struct

In C++, I have two structs (assume all members are public):

```
struct A{
   t1 d1;
   t2 d2;
   t3 d3;
   ...
   t100 d100;
};

struct B{
   t7 d7;
   t3 d3;
   t5 d5;
};
```

The members in B is a subset of A's members.

Now I need a function to copy all members from B to A:

```
func(A a, B b) {
    a.d7 = b.d7;
    a.d3 = b.d3;
    a.d5 = b.d5;
}
```

What is the elegant way to implement `func` without explicitly listing all `B`'s members? Giving `A` is fixed and can't be modified.

Comment: You can inherit `B` from `A`, put the common field in `A`, the others in `B`, thus pass a reference to `A` to some functions and a reference to `B` to some others. This is not exactly what polymorphism is meant for, but it solves your problem the way you want, that is to not copy fields from `B` to `A`. I won't do that anyway.

Comment: @AndyG: The OP said it is C++ and it's easy to imagine that some type like `t1` might be a C++ type like `std::string`, which would make a big difference.

Comment: You might find adapting `A` and `B` to a Boost.Fusion struct to be helpful. Or, soon, a Boost.Hana equivalent.

Comment: @AndyG: rephrase your wording.

Comment: Sorry about the C/C++ confusion. The `t1` - `t100` are just POD types. They are not any STL or object.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: True. I wanted to point out that such a syntax for declaring a `struct` is considered obsolete now. Probably OPs teacher was teaching C++ from a heavy C background. [Kate Gregory's CPPCon 2015 talk, "Stop teaching C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)

Comment: @AndyG The code is what I copied somewhere. I've changed it to C++ style now. Please ignore the difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you were allowed to change A, you could express the structural relationship between A and B:

- A could inherit from B , if A is in reality a kind of B.  You can then remove the common elements from A (because they are inherited from B).
- A could have a B member replacing the common elements.

In this case you could enjoy the use of `=`  (in the first case you'd use slicing on purpose, in the second case, it would be a clean assignment).

If you can't express the structural relationship, there is no general safe approach but have a list of assignements as you have.

You should not consider memcopy() approach or similar as you can't be sure that the elements have the same alignment.  And if it's not a POD element, this could cause undefined behaviour (memory leaks, corruptions, virtual function table corrupted, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Example you gave:

```
func(A a, B b) {
    a.d7 = b.d7;
    a.d3 = b.d3;
    a.d5 = b.d5;
}
```

Looks like a good place for a macro:

```
func(A a, B b) {
#define c(f) a.f = b.f
    c(d7);
    c(d3);
    c(d5);
#undef c
}
```

Comment: Oh please don't do this, not only is it longer than the original but it doesn't debug and it's harder to read.

Comment: But still I need to list all B's members. The best solution in my mind is to find a way to iterate B's members -- But not sure how I can do it.

Comment: @stanleyli You can't :(

Answer (score 0):

> What is the elegant way to implement `func` without explicitly listing all `B`'s members?

### In your case, there is NO other way.

If you were using C++ and `struct A` was modifiable, then you could have used `class` and utilized the already existing, elegant facilities of copy constructor:

```
class_name (const class_name & class_object)
```

and copy assignment:

```
class_name & class_name::operator= (const class_name & class_object)
```

---

Here are links to [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and [copy assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) further reading.